# Creating a program that works out the price of a flight based on some variables. Want to learn how to reduce the number of if statements

Tags: java

The task was to calculate the cost of a flight for a customer based on: the city they were flying to, the number of adult seats purchased and the number of child seats purchased.

I am still a beginner to programming and was wanting to find a way to reduce the number of if statements that I have had to use. The program runs perfectly as is, but I think it is sloppy. Any suggestions?

```
    int Johannesburg [] = {780,658}; //flight price for adult and child respectively
    int CapeTown [] = {1020,965}; 
    int Bloemfontein [] = {945,835}; 

    int totPrice = 0; // intialization of final price value

    String cityChoice = (String)cmbDest.getSelectedItem(); //city that the customer is flying to
    int adults = (Integer)jSpinner1.getValue(); //number of adults flying
    int kids = (Integer)jSpinner2.getValue(); //number of children flying 

    if(cityChoice.equals("Johannesburg")){
        totPrice = Johannesburg[0]*adults + Johannesburg[1]*kids;
    }
    if(cityChoice.equals("Cape Town")){
        totPrice = CapeTown[0]*adults + CapeTown[1]*kids;
    }
    if(cityChoice.equals("Bloemfontein")){
        totPrice = Bloemfontein[0]*adults + Bloemfontein[1]*kids;
    }
    jTextArea1.setText("Your booking for " + adults + " adult ticket(s) and " + kids + "children ticket(s) for " + cityChoice + " will cost R" + totPrice); //output statement
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Java 7 or above, you can make use of the switch statement. See example here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: Thanks, that seems like exactly what I need. However, when I tried to use the switch statement it had a problem with the switch statement being of type int and the case being a string. How do I fix that?

Comment: Before JDK7, the switch statement only supported int. JDK 7 brought support for Strings. Can you check your JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a structure like "x -> y" (in your case city -> prices) then a map is always a good start. It's also better to store different data (price adult/child) in an object instead of an array.

Start like this:

```
Map<String, FlightPrice> = new HashMap<>();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Could you give me some guidance on how to put the values into an object?

Comment: Into the Map or objects in general? The Map has a put function. For all of its functions just check the official doc. If you want to know how to create classes like FlightPrice in general, then you should start with some basic Java tutorial. You will get to this point very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below, Then you can call the method by passing the cityName and and a map of your city Names and and their arrays(kid+parent)

```
public void calculatePrice(Map<String,int[]> cityMap,String cityName)
        {
            return totalPrice= totalPrice=cityMap.get(cityName)[0]+cityMap.get(cityName)[1];
        }
```